# Display single row for each group in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Assume I have a `data.table` with a grouping variable (`Group`) and a few other columns.

```
DT <- data.table(Group=rep(1:10, each=5), x=rnorm(50), y=rep(runif(10), each=5), z=rep(rnorm(10), each=5))
```

I'm interested in just getting e.g. the first row for each `Group` variable, so the desired output would be something like

```
Group        x        y        z
    1  -0.9331   0.4765  -0.3284
    2   0.3902   0.3514   1.7344
    3  -0.7205   0.8793   0.0246
```

And so on. Ultimately, I'm interested in the `y` column (which should have one value per `Group`), but I would like to see also the `Group` and `z` columns. I know I can do something like

```
DT[, .(unique(y), unique(z)), by=Group]
```

But is there a way to just get all columns?

Comment: What about `DT[, .SD[1L], by = Group]`  That gives you the first row in each group

Comment: Ah, of course, that works perfectly. Brilliant in its simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: if somebody is more comfortable with functions there is always `DT[, head(.SD,1), by = Group]`. @RichardScriven you should post answer

Comment: @RichardScriven - I recall something about the `.SD` slowing things down and how using `.I` is preferential - maybe `DT[DT[,.I==.I[1],by=Group]$V1]` or something? It's buried somewhere in old questions but I can't find it.

Comment: @thelatemail it looks like this one should be fixed already in [data.table#735](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735).

Comment: @thelatemail I'm not sure about performance differences, but for this specific use case, I'm working with pretty small DT's (~40K rows) so your solution only knocks off about 0.5ms (the median difference when running `microbenchmark` 1e3 times). But thanks for the tip! It's always good to know alternatives

Comment: @jangorecki - ok, cool, I knew there was ongoing work, so good to see it completed.

Comment: The fastest solution will be just `unique(DT, by = "Group")` though